# What is the equivalent of ElasticsearchRestTemplate interface in 5.0

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

What is the equivalent of `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.ElasticsearchRestTemplate` for support beyond 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the interface `ElasticsearchOperations` in your code and have that injected instead of a concrete implementation like the `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.ElasticsearchRestTemplate`. If you'd do this, then you would just update your configuration, and the injected class will then be an instance of `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate` which implements `ElasticsearchOperations` as well.